# What is the meaning/usage of あのね/あのな at the start of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> によによ
>
> によによ
>
> ちょ、なによ、その顔{かお}？何{なに}か言いたい{いいたい}の、二人{ふたり}とも？
>
> 何{なに}もありません。ただ、今{いま}はこういう反応{はんのう}をすべきかと思いまして{おもいまして}。
>
> 俺{おれ}はサイエに自分{じぶん}と同じ{おなじ}顔{かお}をしろと言われて{いわれて}な。
>
> で、この「によによ」に、なにか意味{いみ}でもあったのか？
>
> あのね…

Occasionally I'll see this usage where someone has said something and then the listener will respond with あのね/あのな (sometimes with nothing said afterwards and appearing to be an expression of exasperation). Does あのね/あのな stand alone as a comment without anything said afterwards (or is the listener suppose to "understand" from context what they are going to say?)

Comment: Do they go on to say something after あのね?

Comment: In this case, no because the scene cuts out(so they may say something or may not) but I've seen it happen both ways.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly used both ways.

> 「あのね + a sentence or even a passage」

= "You know, ~~~~~~~"

> 「あのね・・ with no words to follow」

= "I'll tell you what.", "Wait a sec.", "Hold on.", "Let me tell you something."

The two 「あのね's」 are (often) pronounced differently.